# How to remove html tags from appearing in phpmyadmin table?

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

When I add a topic to be stored in my MySQL database, in the description column the information entered is opened and closed with p tags. How do I remove them from the table and prevent this from happening again?

Here's the code:

```html
<?php

include(ROOT_PATH . "/app/database/db.php");

$table = 'topicstable';
$topics = selectAll($table);

if (isset($_POST['add_topic'])) {
  unset($_POST['add_topic']);

  $topic_id = create($table, $_POST);
  $_SESSION['message'] = 'Topic created successfully';
  $_SESSION['type'] = 'msg';
  header('Location: ' . BASE_URL . '/admin/topics/indextopics.php');
  exit();
}

 ?>
```

```html
            <form class="" action="createtopics.php" method="post">
              <div class="add-form-div">
                <label class="cplabel">Name</label>
                <input class="text-input" type="text" name="name" value="">
              </div>

              <div class="add-form-div">
                <label class="cplabel">Description</label>
                <br>
                <textarea class="" id="body" name="description"></textarea>
              </div>

              <div class="add-form-div">
                <button class="admin-button" type="submit" name="add_topic">Add Topic</button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: For starters, whenever you store some user inputted information into a database, escape the string, look up "php mysqli escape string" based on how you're storing the data, whether you use direct or procedural, here's a helpful link: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: Now that you've looked up, `mysqli_real_escape_string`, forget it and never use it. Use [mysqli_prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)d statements.

Comment: I've included a rich text editor in my CMS and it is that that's causing the html tags to be added. Might that change anything?